# Is it possible to tag an Action with both GET and DELETE verb in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-3

I'd like to do `GET /Product/1` and `DELETE /Product/1` instead of having to have a separate action like `DELETE /Product/Delete/1`:

For example:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... }
}
```

How do I distinguish between the HTTP verbs within the action body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would separate out the logic into two different methods.

If you need the same method signature but different http methods then you should be able to do the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... }

[ActionName("index")]
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult IndexDelete(int id) { ... }
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I forgot about the ActionName decorator.

Comment: You can also do `[HttpDelete]public ActionResult Index(int id, string foo) { }` if you want to avoid using `ActionName`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use Get|Delete on the same action because that's just confusing. There's no reason for one method to do two things. [One method does One thing](http://blog.yapb.net/post/2010/02/12/Curlys-Law.aspx).

That would suck.

To get around that, create an `ActionResult` that actually deletes, and add the `HttpDelete` attribute to it.

This is the preferred way of doing it:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
    }

    [HttpDelete]    
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {

    }
}
```

See here for more on [Delete and Get](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/why_put_and_delete.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I addressed that specifically in my question (instead of doing DELETE /Product/Delete/1, where Delete in the URL is the Action. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @johansson It wasn't unclear: You shouldn't do what you're trying to do.  It's not good design.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. You are not saving in any code or benefiting from mixing an idempotent `GET` with a potentially dangerous `DELETE`. What if they have different caching requirement? Or different authorization?